# An efficient, optimized code for matching rows in a huge matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, row, matching

I have a huge matrix on which I need to do some matching operation. Here's the code I have written and it works fine, but I think there is some room to make it more optimized or write another code that does the matching in less time. Could you please help me with that?

```
rowsMatched = find(bigMatrix(:, 1) == matchingRow(1, 1) 
        & bigMatrix(:, 2) == matchingRow(1, 2) 
        & bigMatrix(:, 3) == matchingRow(1, 3))
```

The problem with this code is that I cannot use `&&` operand. So, in case one of the columns do not match, the program still checks the next condition. How can I avoid this?

**Update**: Here's the solution to this problem:

```
rowsMatched = find(all(bsxfun(@eq, bigMatrix, matchingRow),2));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to do it in a vectorized manner:

```
rowsMatched = find(all(bsxfun(@eq, bigMatrix, matchingRow),2));
```

Notice that it will work for any number of columns, just `matchingRow` should have the same number of columns as `bigMatrix`.

Comment: Thanks, one of the benefits of using your method is that it makes my code flexible in terms of matching different ``matchingRow`` matrices with ``bigMatrix`` matrices, but it's slower than the code I have written ... . Do you think there is a way that I can take the advantage of ``&&`` instead of ``&``?

Comment: I think you can apply `&&` only if you do it in a loop, row by row.